# Dynamic alocation an array of Images in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I want to make a game of BlackJack.

I want to make a vector of images and when I press a button a new image shows up(need 2 or 3 images).

After that I want to delete all of them in another button press.

I try to declare an vector in main class(Unit1.h):

```
class TForm1 : public TForm{
```

...

```
public: TImage* Images[];
```

And in Form1(Unit1.cpp):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    //  i=1 is global 
    Images[i] =new TImage(this);
    Images[i]->Parent=this;
    Images[i]->Picture->Bitmap->...//here i want to use it 
    i++;
}
```

And here i want to delete them:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    for(int k=1;k<=i;i++) {
        Images[k]->~TImage();   //delete Images[k];
    }
}
```

Comment: a) I see no usage of `vector`, and  b) why are you explicitly calling the destructor here `Images[k]->~TImage()`?  and c), C++ array indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Yes I don't have a vector ,and there I want to delete that images ,it is a worng way with destructor?  I have seen it works with delete

Comment: Do not call the destructor explicitly.  https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#dont-call-dtor-on-obj-allocd-via-new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not declare a vector.  [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is an actual class type in C++. What you actually declared is a static array of unknown size. You cannot do that. You must specify a constant for the size at compile-time, eg:

```
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
...
public:
    TImage* Images[3];
};
```

If you do not know the number of images at compile-time, you must declare a **pointer** to an array that is dynamically allocated at runtime instead:

```
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
...
public:
    TImage** Images;
    int TotalNumberOfImages;
    int NumberOfImages;

    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent *Owner);
    __fastcall ~TForm1();
};
```

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent *Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
{
    TotalNumberOfImages = ...;
    Images = new TImage*[TotalNumberOfImages];
    NumberOfImages = 0;
}
__fastcall TForm1::~TForm1()
{
    delete[] Images;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (NumberOfImages < TotalNumberOfImage)
    {
        TImage *img = new TImage(this);
        img->Parent = this;
        img->Picture->...
        ...
        Images[NumberOfImages++] = img;
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < NumberOfImages; ++k)
        delete Images[k];
    NumberOfImages = 0;
}
```

If you really want to use a `std::vector`, it should be more like this instead:

```
#include <vector>

class TForm1 : public TForm
{
...
public:
    std::vector<TImage*> Images;
};
```

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TImage *img = new TImage(this);
    img->Parent = this;
    img->Picture->...
    ...
    Images.push_back(img);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < Images.size(); ++k)
        delete Images[k];
    /*
    or:
    for(std::vector<TImage*>::iterator iter = Images.begin(), end = Images.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
        delete *iter;
    */

    Images.clear();
}
```

Or, if you are using one of Embarcadero's Clang-based C++11 compilers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class TForm1 : public TForm
{
...
public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TImage*>> Images;
};
```

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    std::unique_ptr<TImage> img(new TImage(this));
    img->Parent = this;
    img->Picture->...
    ...
    Images.push_back(img);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Images.clear();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps me alot