# C++ Builder how to build dynamic Objects with vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, image, dynamic, vector

I am developing IOS application in C++ Builder . My question is how to build TImages in a for loop. I declared the vector in public :

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<TImage*> Image(c); // public declaration 

void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < c ; i++){

    c = 5 // c should be send to te array
    Image[i] = new TImage(this); // I tried it this way but when i click the button i get an acess violence error
    Image[i]->Parent = BoardItem ;
    Image[i]->Height = 20 ; 
    Image[i]->Width = 20 ; 
   }
}
```

So how do i create Images in a for loop using vector ?

[Dynamic alocation an array of Images in C++ Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141850/dynamic-alocation-an-array-of-images-in-c-builder) I looked up the last answer to that question but there isn't described how to do it in a loop .

Comment: What is the value of `c` when you do `std::vector<TImage*> Image(c);`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my problem is solved :)

Comment: Please put the answer you got as an answer, to help others.

Comment: @JesseWatZ Wasn't mine helpful enough to sketch it out?

Comment: I didn't realize you had made one when I commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `// c should be send to te array`

It won't change the size of the array if you change the variable `c` value.

You have to call `resize()` on the `Image` vector to change the size, but it's not really suitable. Better write something like

```
void TForm1::ClearImage() {
 for (int i = 0; i < Image.size(); ++i) {
     delete Image[i];
 }
 Image.clear();
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 ClearImage();
 c=5;
 for (int i = 0; i < c ; i++){

    Image.push_back(new TImage(this));
    Image.back()->Parent = BoardItem ;
    Image.back()->Height = 20 ; 
    Image.back()->Width = 20 ; 
   }
}
```

Comment: and how do i name the images ?  they couldn't have the same name ? Aren't they all named Image ?

Comment: My first though too, but he has already created a vector with 5 default constructed elements.

Comment: Thanks to that it is all working very fine but one question left . why do i have to Image.clear() when i delete the images in a loop above ?

Comment: @Philip1895 You delete the objects there that were formerly created with `new`. `clear()` is needed to reset the `vector`.

Comment: Ok thanks but don't i have to Clear it also on the form destroy ?

Comment: @Philip1895 Yes. Best you provide that first loop with a small private function you can reuse.

Comment: well i don't understand that , isn't it enough to Image.clear() on FormDestroy ?

Comment: @Philip1895 No, the important part is the `delete` to avoid memory leaks. But for consistency call `clear()` as well.

Comment: ok then i am doing another loop on the form destroy to delete the images :)